# Set datetime variable to next day at 12 am using sql

Tags: sql, datetime, stored-procedures, job-scheduling, sql-job

I am writing a SQL job and I have to set the schedule running stamp to daily at 12:00:00 AM. The date format should be 2017-05-10 00:00:00.000
I have done something like this. But I don't know how to set the exact date and time(which is crucial). Please help

```
 SET @ScheduledStStamp = GETDATE() + 1
```

Comment: [tag:sql] is for the ANSI Standard language. Unfortunately, database products vary *vastly* in how their datetime features work. Please edit and add a tag for your database product (e.g. Oracle, MySQL, SQL Server, etc).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you need to set the date as Tomorrow's date, use Dateadd(d,1,getdate()).

Then convert that date first to varchar(8) and then back to datetime.This will set your time in '00:00:00.000' format.

```
 select convert(datetime,convert(varchar(8),Dateadd(d,1,getdate()),112))
```

Assign it your variable as below

```
   Declare @ScheduledStStamp datetime
   SET @ScheduledStStamp =convert(datetime,convert(varchar(8),Dateadd(d,1,getdate()),112))
   select @ScheduledStStamp
```

Answer (score 0):

I used the below code to get the desired result

```
SET @ScheduledStStamp = CONVERT(DATETIME, CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE() + 1))
```

Answer (score 0):

Today's date:

```
SELECT DATEADD(d,0,DATEDIFF(d,0,GETDATE()))
```

Tomorrow:

```
SELECT DATEADD(d,1,DATEDIFF(d,0,GETDATE()))
```

Yesterday:

```
SELECT DATEADD(d,-1,DATEDIFF(d,0,GETDATE()))
```